# How to add both videos and images to an image slider with thumbnails?

Tags: html, css

```
<!-- Below are the images in the gallery -->
<div id="img-1" data-img-id="1" class="img-wrapper active" style="background-image: url('/images/1.jpg')"></div>
<div id="img-2" data-img-id="2" class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')"></div>
<div id="img-3" data-img-id="3" class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpg')"></div>
```

This is how my gallery looks:

[image]

How can i add videos to this gallery?

Comment: Which slider are you used?

Comment: add video tag between div with out padding